To account for empty date periods
Please help me with a difficult task
I have a table that contains payments by date, for example:
date       sum
2023-11-01 1
2023-12-01 2
2024-02-01 1

I need to find the minimum amount for the last 2 months, but if there is no data for any month in the table, for example, for the period 2024-01-01 there is no data at all, then the minimum amount will be 0.

You need to start by generating a list of all the dates you want in your result - either permanently in a table or dynamically in a CTE (or similar)

So, what is the problem? You get today's date, get the last two months, select the data for these two months, build a sum. The result will be NULL when there is no data. COALESCE(sum, 0) will make this NULL a zero.

One of the options is to create recursive cte (named it dates in code below) that will generate all the dates you need (10 in this answer). You should Left Join your data to the recursive cte (ON DAY_IDs) and use Coalesce() function to replace null values (missing dates in your data) with 0.
WITH
  RECURSIVE 
    dates AS     -- a cte generating last 10 dates from current date
      ( Select CURRENT_DATE as DAY_ID, 10 as NUM_OF_DAYS
       Union All
        Select CURRENT_DATE - ( NUM_OF_DAYS - 1 ), NUM_OF_DAYS - 1
        From dates
        Where NUM_OF_DAYS > 1
      ),

  tbl AS    -- S a m p l e    D a t a :
    ( Select DATE '2024-05-17' as DAY_ID, 1 as AMOUNT Union All
      Select DATE '2024-05-21', 2 Union All
      Select DATE '2024-05-22', 1 
    )

--    S Q L :
Select        d.DAY_ID, Coalesce(t.AMOUNT, 0) as AMOUNT
From          dates d
Left Join     tbl t ON t.DAY_ID = d.DAY_ID
Order By      d.DAY_ID

/*    R e s u l t :
day_id      amount
----------  ------
2024-05-17       1
2024-05-18       0
2024-05-19       0
2024-05-20       0
2024-05-21       2
2024-05-22       1
2024-05-23       0
2024-05-24       0
2024-05-25       0
2024-05-26       0    */

